# Splitting Variable w/ JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I thought I could split a string inside a jquery function using the JavaScript `.split` method. The code below stores string as "value1, value2, value3".

If I try to split that string and then alert the item, nothing happens. Any ideas?
I have verified that `string_sp` is correct so I know the issue is with the split line.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link_pressed').click(function() {
        var string_sp = $('select.s_box').val();
        var box_str = string_sp.split(',');
        alert(box_str[0]);
    });                 
});
```

Comment: Andrew Whitaker's edit fixed the syntax error...

Comment: @landons I saw the error too, but I think H Patel corrected it just before Whitakers edit. Otherwise it would be shown in the edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error (didn't close the click function call).  Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.link_pressed').click(function() {
    var string_sp = $('select.s_box').val();
    var box_str = string_sp.split(',');
    alert(box_str[0]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double-check your assumptions.

```
var string_sp = "value1, value2, value3";
string_sp.split(',');
```

Results in:

```
["value1", " value2", " value3"]
```

And:

```
var string_sp = "value1, value2, value3";
var box_str = string_sp.split(',');
box_str[0];
```

results in:

```
"value1"
```